# Return a Dependent Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm hoping this is a simple thing I'm missing, but I can't seem to return data as I'd like to. My function login takes a username, and returns the password and id for authentication, along with the users XY coordinates from the database.

The XY coordinates are dependent on the ID returned from the login query, which are all returned as a `Promise` to the main function for authentication. However, I can't seen to return all the data into one nicely knit object.

```
function login(user) {
    var query = 'SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+mysql.escape(user);
    return db.select(query).then(function(rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        return Promise.all([
            getX(rows[0].id),
            getY(rows[0].id)
        ]);
    });
}
```

This logs:

```
[ { password: 'nopasswordforu', //<-- not a real password
    id: 9 } ]
[ [ { x: 32 } ], [ { y: 36 } ] ]
```

The password is logging from the console statement, not the return. The only thing returned is the `xy` coordinates. How can I return the query results in the same Promise as the function returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function login(user) {
    var query = 'SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+mysql.escape(user);
    return db.select(query).then(function(rows) {
        // Promise.all is unnecessary if the caller calls .spread()
        return [getX(rows[0].id), getY(rows[0].id), rows[0]];
    });
}

login(...).spread(function(x, y, user){
    console.log(x, y, user.password, user.id);
})
```

Comment: always wonderful to hear from you -- however just a heads up `db.select` is a custom function so it's already async :)

Comment: Odd, it wont let me tag you in comments. I'll give this a shot, thank you vurry much!

Comment: @RUJordan It won't let you tag people who are already going to be notified (i.e. the author of an answer is always notified about comments on that answer).

Comment: Now to wait until we get `.spread` in ES6 support in browsers :/ no destructoring sucks in Promise.coroutine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
    return Promise.all([
        getX(rows[0].id),
        getY(rows[0].id)
    ]).then(function(xCoord,yCoord) {
      return Promise.all([{
          password:rows[0].password,
          x:xCoord[0].x,
          y:yCoord[0].y
      }]);
    });
```

The latter piece of code would look something like this:

```
login('username').then(function(data) {
/* 
 exposed:

 data.password,
 data.x,
 data.y

*/
});
```

Note that I am making the assumption that getX and getY are async functions here, which is why you are calling `Promise.all()` around them.

Comment: Could you give an explanation? Your answer is currently incomplete.